# Cache a very costly nativequery that reurns a boolean in a JpaRepository

Tags: java, jpa, caching

How to achieve that? I'd like to do it the JPA way, Not the hibernate one. Cacheable seems to work only for entities, but not Booleans.

My query is a heavy recursive one, but it simply returns a booelan. Can I cache in an easy way 2 calls with the same incoming arguments and evict later when I know the underlying data has changed?

Comment: Isn't adding Cacheable annotation on the Service component helping? https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and

Comment: The problem is the service layer process other things which I would not like to cache.. For me the optimal way would be at RepositoryLevel... its just a boolean

Comment: You can just create one service layer method which will just call the repository method..

Comment: If so, how can I make it @Cacheable just as long as wrapping transaction lasts?

Comment: cache WHAT? The compilation of SQL? The query result? Provide code in example form to demonstrate your "problem"